# Using after_update with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I have an `Artist` that's linked to a `Board` model. I'd like to setup an `after_update` callback that for every update to the artists name I'd like to change the board's name as so:

```
after_update { self.board.update_attribute(:name, name: name) }
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass
```

I notice that the dropoff is with the association itself. Why is this happening? For what it's worth I also have an `after_create` callback that would create a board by default:

```
after_create { board.create(name: self.name) }
```

---

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :board, as: :boardable, dependent: :destroy

  after_create { board.create(name: self.name) }
  after_update { self.board.update_attribute(:name, name: name) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to create the associated board is `create_board(name: self.name)`, check the references for `has_one` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

You could do `.create` or `.build` for 1<->N (with has_many, has_many through or has and belongs to many), but for a 1<->1 you can't.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, my approach created a board but doesn't actually pass the boardable reference, which in turn caused the `after_update` callback not to work? Either way thanks for the help.

Comment: @CarlEdwards, the error you're getting is during the create.  You weren't actually creating any boards at all.  At create time, the value of `self.board` is nil, so you were effectively calling `nil.create`.

Comment: Great. Thank you for clarifying.